# What is the better way to place link in tweets for better UX for max. engagement?

Tags: user-behavior, social-media, social-interfaces, twitter

The most common way of placing link in tweet is:

```
Tweet Text followed by LINK
```

like:

> The ABCs of Landing Pages That Work [Infographic]
>   http://t.co/qeJUFrY93H

---

However, recently I have been tracking @buffer posting there some of the tweets like :

> What I Learned Doing Customer Support For a Week
>   http://t.co/VwJVPR5vw5 Would you give this a try?
>
> Inside The Buffer Retreat: http://t.co/xjIsc2o5Rb How and why we spent
>   $111,874 meeting face-to-face!

i.e.

```
Tweet text LINK tweet text
```

So, Is it something that placing the link between tweet text will result more clicks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this. 
But, design logic would say **yes, inline links should work better on average**.

Many twitter links have been shortened so it's difficult to tell what the contents of the link are.

This creates hesitation for the user because she has to figure out whether to click the link.

Users will typically try to figure out what the link contains by reading the surrounding text.

Most users process content left to right, even when that content is visually "chunked" so that the reader can see the whole line at once.

By providing some descriptive text before the link, the user is more naturally led to click on the link, because she will have read the preamble before she processes the link.

That provides users with **slightly lower cognitive friction** than seeing the link first, reading the text, than backtracking to click the link.

This may nor may not result in better clickthrough *rates*, but it's likely to result in better clickthrough *intent* (quality).

Comment: If I got it right - your answer first talks in favour of inline links and ending paras about placing links at the end ?

Comment: though the points really makes sense - especially this one - `reading the text, than backtracking to click the link`

Comment: @exexzian yes that'd be the conclusion!

Comment: yeah thankx for the answer and showing clear insights